# MyEclipse Remove Server Connectors

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

Not a programming question per se, but does anyone know how to remove the default MyEclipse Derby and MyEclipse Tomcat servers in 2015 CI?  I have googled and looked through the xml/ini files without a solution

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MyEclipse 2015 you can hide the MyEclipse Derby and Tomcat servers from the Servers view.

Please check the screenshot at [this link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2e4ysdw.jpg) :

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just saw your post and it worked!

Comment: For those that cannot access the screenshot - Access the Servers Menu in the Servers View by clicking on the down-pointing triangle in the top right of the view (right next to minimize). The first option will read "Hide Embedded Servers" which will expand to show options to disable both "MyEclipse Tomcat v7.0" and "MyEclipse Derby"

Answer (score 1):

You can try disable Tomcat through :
`Window > Preferences > MyEclipse > Server > Tomcat > Tomcat 7` disable radio button

And if you can't do it the same way for `MyEclipse Derby` you could disable the plugin if you're not using it through :
`Windows->Preferences then select General -> Startup and Shutdown`